# How to use if in var field check validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code for input validate:

```
var ex_info = {
   email: {type: "email", config: {require: true}},
    amount_from: {type: "text", config: {require: true, is_chars: ",.[:num]"}},
    wallet_from: {type: "text", config: {require: true}},
    phone: {type: "text", config: {require: false, is_chars: "+[:num]", min: 6}},
    name: {type: "text", config: {require: true}},
    fname: {type: "text", config: {require: true}}
};
```

How to use `if(){} else {}` for that field `wallet_from: {type: "text", config: {require: true}},` ? I want to switch `required` to `true` or `false` by condition.

Comment: Declare a variable, set in in the `if` condition then use that variable as the value of the property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
ex_info.wallet_from.config.require = condition
```

Or if `condition` is not a boolean:

```
ex_info.wallet_from.config.require = !!condition
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional operator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```
ex_info.wallet_from.config.require = myCondition === isTrue ? true : false
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ternary (replace 'conditional statement' with whatever you are testing for):
ex_info.wallet_from.config.require = *conditional statement* ? true : false;